# Laravel Categories Map Relationship

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship, has-many-through

I have the following three tables but I don't know how to build a relation between the category and the other data type, in this case 'Page':

posts:

```
post_id    | title        | slug
1          | Test         | test
2          | Another test | another test
```

catgory_map:

```
id | category_id | referrer_id | category_map_type
1  | 2           | 1           | Post
2  | 3           | 2           | Post
3  | 2           | 9           | Page
```

category

```
id | name
1  | Laravel
2  | Zend2
3  | Phalcon
```

So whenever I read a Category I like to be able to do something like this

```
foreach($category->destinations) ...
```

I have tried until now with hasManyThrough but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a [many-to-many relation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many) with some additional filtering on the relationship (for the `category_map_type`). Try this:

#### Post model

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'category_map', 'referrer_id')
                ->where('category_map_type', 'Post');
}
```

#### Category model

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Post', 'category_map', 'category_id', 'referrer_id')
                ->where('category_map_type', 'Post');
}
```

#### Usage

```
$category = Category::find(1);
foreach($category->posts as $post){
    // ...
}
```

(And the same goes for `Post`)

---

You might also want to look into [polymorphic many-to-many relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)